# SQLで指定の条件に達した年度を出したい

Tags: sql, oracle

休暇日数を社員ごとに古い順に積算して、合計10を超えた年度を知りたいです。
考え方のヒントだけでも頂けると大変助かります。

**対象のデータ**

```
| 年度 | 社員ID | 休暇日数   
+------+--------+-----------+
| 2014 | 00001  | 5        
| 2015 | 00001  | 3        
| 2016 | 00001  | 7        
| 2017 | 00001  | 4
| 2014 | 00002  | 4
| 2017 | 00002  | 6
| 2019 | 00002  | 10
```

**期待する結果**

```
社員ID | 年度  
-------+--------
00001  | 2016
00002  | 2017
```

Comment: [How to calculate running total in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38115722/) が参考になるかと思います。また、"oracle sql cumulative sum" などで検索してみるのも良いかと。

Answer (score 2):

標準的なSQLの範囲で書いてみました。
ある社員のある年度までの合計休暇日数の一覧を出して、10日を超えているもので絞り込み、年度の最小を出す、をそのまま書き下しています。

#### テーブル定義

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PaidLeaveDays( 
  yeras int not null
  , employee_id int not null
  , paid_leave_days int not null
);
```

#### 抽出SQL

```
SELECT
  MIN(pld10.years) AS years
  , pld10.employee_id 
FROM
  ( 
    SELECT
      pld2.years
      , pld2.employee_id
      , sum(pld1.paid_leave_days) AS paid_leave_days_total 
    FROM
      PaidLeaveDays AS pld1 
      INNER JOIN PaidLeaveDays pld2 
        ON pld1.employee_id = pld2.employee_id 
        AND pld1.years <= pld2.years 
    GROUP BY
      pld2.years
      , pld2.employee_id 
    HAVING
      paid_leave_days_total >= 10
  ) AS pld10 
GROUP BY
  pld10.employee_id;
```

#### 結果

```
years   employee_id
2016    1
2017    2
```